# Google Chart: Overlapping bars - bring latest to front

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization, bar-chart, overlap

Here's picture of my bar chart using Google Charts and the corresponding values on the right side. X-Axis is a Date Axis

[image]

As you can see in the table, there are two values for 16th Jan, 2017 (100 & 60). They're overlapping and though 60 is the latest reading (considering time), it is not showing in the graph. It is behind 100. How can I bring the latest reading to the front. Is there any setting in Google Chart that does this?

Comment: can't find an option that would _bring to front_, you could possibly stack the bars or add a time value to separate the dates...

Comment: I can't do that because on hover (on the bar), it shows both date and time.

Comment: you can provide a custom tooltip, another option would be to use use string values on the x-axis, instead of dates...

Answer (score 1):

My requirement was that I only needed to bring the latest value to the front.

My value list was sorted in descending order by time. So I reversed the list and problem solved.

```
this.myValueList = this.myValueList.reverse();
```

If there are two overlapping bars, google charts bring to front the later one by position in the array

Comment: Reversing sounds like a hack (glad that it works for you though). You should be filtering that list and only passing to the chart values that you want to display.

Comment: I had no other option but to reverse, since the same data is used for the table on the right.